# Why is the transform control at the 3d cursor and not at the selected vertex? How do I fix this? [SOLVED]

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor, origin, transform-orientation

[image]

I just want the controls at the selection. I know I can hit G then axis but I would still like to know how to get the controls at the selection. This is blender 2.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the *Transform Pivot Point* panel, you must have the *3D Cursor* selected, instead of *Median Point* for example:

[image]